# Select values from multiple dictionaries into list of objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to select OrderId & Row from multiple dictionaries and create a list of Orders which contains a list of Rows.

The code I'm struggling with this far is:

```
var listOfDictionaries = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict1.Add("OrderId", "12345");      
dict1.Add("Row", "1");              
listOfDictionaries.Add(dict1);

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict2.Add("OrderId", "97845");
dict2.Add("Row", "10");
listOfDictionaries.Add(dict2);

var dict3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict3.Add("OrderId", "12345");
dict3.Add("Row", "2");
listOfDictionaries.Add(dict3);

var grouped = listOfDictionaries.SelectMany(d => 
                 d.Where(kvp => 
                    kvp.Key.ToLower().Contains("orderid") || kvp.Key.ToLower().Contains("row")))
              .GroupBy(a => a.Key).ToList();

public class Order 
{
    public Order() 
    {
       OrderRows = new List<OrderRow>();
    }

    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderRow> OrderRows { get; set; }
}

public class OrderRow 
{
    public string OrderRowId { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone have a good idea how to solve this?

Comment: SelectMany would flatten them so a bad idea.

Comment: Hope the code after dict3 adds value in dict3 and not in dict2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first select the orders and then the occording rows like so.

```
var orderFieldName = "OrderId";
var orders = listOfDictionaries.Select(dict => dict[orderFieldName]).Distinct();
var grouped = orders.Select(order => new Order
{
    OrderId = order,
    OrderRows = listOfDictionaries.Where(dict => dict[orderFieldName] == order)
        .Select(item => new OrderRow {OrderRowId = item["Row"]}).ToList()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting following exception: 
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: @Henrik Look at the code of the third dictionary. You add the entries there to the second. `dict2.Add("Row", "2");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
var result = listOfDictionaries.Select(x => new { OrderId = x["OrderId"], Row = x["Row"] })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.OrderId)
                   .Select(x => new { OrderId = x.Key, Values = x.Select(y => y.Row) });
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel you dictionary code will not run since it will not allow you to enter duplicate key value in same list. So here I have create a solution using list of Struct

```
class Stackoverflow
{
    struct OrderData
    {
        public string OrderID { get; set; }
        public string Row { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strInputOrderID = "ORD1";

        ////Using Struct List
        List<OrderData> objOrderDataList = new List<OrderData>();

        OrderData objOrderData = new OrderData();
        objOrderData.OrderID = "ORD1";
        objOrderData.Row = "1";
        objOrderDataList.Add(objOrderData);

        objOrderData = new OrderData();
        objOrderData.OrderID = "ORD2";
        objOrderData.Row = "2";
        objOrderDataList.Add(objOrderData);

        objOrderData = new OrderData();
        objOrderData.OrderID = "ORD3";
        objOrderData.Row = "3";
        objOrderDataList.Add(objOrderData);

        objOrderData = new OrderData();
        objOrderData.OrderID = "ORD1";
        objOrderData.Row = "4";
        objOrderDataList.Add(objOrderData);

        List<OrderData> resultOrderDataList = (from data in objOrderDataList
                                               where data.OrderID.Equals(strInputOrderID)
                                               select data).ToList();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have run it and its working fine.
Kindly check and do let me know in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Nikhil Agrawal said:

Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lOmRy9)

```
var result = listOfDictionaries
            .Select(x => new { OrderId = x["OrderId"], Row = x["Row"] })
            .GroupBy(x => x.OrderId)
            .Select(x => new Order{
                OrderId = x.Key, 
                OrderRows = x.Select(y => new OrderRow{OrderRowId = y.Row}).ToList()
            });
```